# Error message on submitting a facebook open graph action

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I have submitted a simple 'vote' open-graph action to facebook. But for some reason there is a 'Changes needed' message in red beside it, instead of the green 'Active' message. Also when I click on the action to check its settings, there is a message at the top which says:

```
Status: Changes needed
Your submission is missing a preposition (ex: on, in, through). 
Please add the appropriate preposition and resubmit.
Please make changes below and resubmit for review.
```

My Action settings are as follows:

```
Define Action Type
Name : Vote
Connected object types: Photo

Configure Story Text
Tenses Supported:Stories for this action should be shown in: both past and present tenses.
Past Tense: Joe voted on [My-app-name]
Plural Past Tense: Joe and two other friends voted
Present Tense: Joe is voting
Plural Present Tense: Joe and two other friends are voting
Imperative Tense: Hey Joe, vote this
```

I haven't added any custom properties to this action.
I have never faced this problem before, while submitting my open graph actions. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I guess I just has to add the preposition after every sentence in 'Configure Story Text'. Hope the action gets accepted!

Answer (score 1):

Your past tense has a preposition "voted on" but your other three just end in the word vote. Add `on` and you should be good.